# In Angular 2+, can I detect when a directive (like routerLink) is applied to my custom component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom button component, like this (simplified):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-button',
    template: `
        <button (click)="handleClick($event)">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </button>
    `
})
export class MyButtonComponent {
    @Output() public onClick: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter();

    handleClick(e) {
        this.onClick.emit(e);
    }
}
```

Normal use case for the button is for user to attach an `onClick` handler. However, some users will want to use button as a link instead, like this:

```
<my-button [routerLink]="'/dashboard'">Go to dashboard</my-button>
```

What I'd like to do in this case is render `my-button` as an `<a>` element instead of literal `<button>`. But in order to do that, I need to detect that user has attached the `[routerLink]` directive to it.

Is there any way to do that?

I know I can just add a boolean `@Input()` prop that will switch the rendering to `<a>` mode, but that feels clunky.

Comment: You'd have to use `@Input()` either way, for `RouterLink`.

Comment: How do you mean, @12seconds? I don't use it now, and links work.

Comment: sorry that's my bad I didn't have RouteModule imported. I will add my answer on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use `@Optional` and `@Host` both are located in `@angular/core`.

On your `my-button` component for typescript you would need to do dependency injection like so:

```
export class MyButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() routerLink: RouterLink) {
     console.log(routerLink)
  }
  ...
}
```

Then on your template you can check if either `routerLink` is null or not and render either `<a>` tag or `<button>` tag

Edit:

To get link working you would need to do this:

```
<a [routerLink]="routerLink.commands">
   Test
</a>
```

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get `<ng-content>` working in `a` tag for some reason.

Edit 2:
Reason why `ng-content` wasn't working is due to multiple `ng-content` in the component, one way to solve this is to use ng-template, for example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hasRouterLink">
  <a [routerLink]="routerLink.commands">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container>
  </a> 
</ng-container>


<ng-container *ngIf="!hasRouterLink">
  <button>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container> 
  </button> 
</ng-container>

<ng-template #contentTpl><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

Comment: This works. Unfortunately, turns out I can't use it to achieve what I wanted (which is to make a link that acts like a link), but it does get me router link instance inside the component.

Comment: @panta82, check my edit on how you would do the link. Created stackblitz for this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztvtpx

Comment: @panta82, another update, FYI on how to fix that multiple `ng-content` issue.

Comment: yeah, I got it working too. Well done.

Several problems.

1) Typescript complains that `commands` is a private property.

2) You now have 2 links, one for top component, one for inner.

3) If you add any additional routerLink params (like replaceUrl), they aren't applied

Comment: I am doing `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]>`, where I have defined a template that holds `ng-content`, and it seems to be working too.

Comment: @panta82, You can try `routerLink.urlTree.toString()` alternative to `routerLink.commands`. I am not sure how you do the replaceUrl. The way I do it seems to work fine `<app-my-button [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [replaceUrl]="true">Show as Link</app-my-button>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to add something bigger than just text as you `ng-content` or there will be some complicated logic for `onClick`? 
I think your case is pretty common and usually it's solved by creating css classes to make buttons and links looks the same. And you can use `<a>` or `<button>` depends on situation and just add necessary classes

Comment: In reality, there is more stuff surrounding ng-content, like spinners and icons.